# Thinkpython book exercise

Tags: python

```
price_book = 24.95
number_books = 60.0/100
first_book_cost = 3
additional_copy = 0.75
discounted_books = price_book*number_books
total_price = discounted_books*(first_book_cost*1+additional_copy*(60-1))

print "The total price of 60 copies of book is %s$."%(total_price)

Suppose the cover price of a book is $24.95, but bookstores get a 40% discount. Shipping costs $3 for the first copy and 75 cents for each additional copy. What is the total wholesale cost for 60 copies?
```

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong!!
The answer should be 523.23, and I am getting 707.33!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The question here isn't very clearly stated.

Do they get a 40% discount on order total/book cost/etc.?

I modeled what I thought you were asking, but I cannot come close to 523.23.

In fact, all books being 40% discounted to 14.97 * 60, comes to 898.20 before shipping costs.

```
#first book costs 24.95
book_cost = 24.95

#they order 60 books
number_books = 60

#shipping cost of book 1 is $3
ship1_cost = 3

#shipping cost for subsequent books is 0.75
ship_cost = 0.75

#print (book 1 + shipping) + (subsequent book qty (59) * unit price) + (subsequent shipping costs (59 * 0.75))
print (book_cost + ship1_cost + ((number_books - 1) * book_cost) + ((number_books - 1) * ship_cost))
```

Comment: They get discount only on the book price, which means in all 60 books and not in the shipping and other stuff, as for the shipping the first book shipping is 3$ and the rest 59 of them are 0.75$

Comment: The discounted total is over 800$ before shipping is calculated.

This formula is probably the easiest to follow

shipping_cost_book_1 + (number_books * book_cost * .6) + ((number_books - 1)* 0.75)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes books, especially free ones, have typos and errors.

According to the information you provided, the total wholesale cost should be:

```
>>> cover_price_of_book = 24.95
>>> shipping_cost_for_first_book = 3.00
>>> shipping_cost_for_additional_books = 0.75
>>> wholesale_cost_of_book = 24.95 * .60
>>> total_number_of_books = 60
>>> total_wholesale_cost = (wholesale_cost_of_book * total_number_of_books) + (shipping_cost_for_first_book + (total_number_of_books - 1) * shipping_cost_for_additional_books)
total_wholesale_cost
945.4499999999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
books= 24.95 * 60
discount= 40/100 * books
shipping= 3+59 * 0.75
total= books - discount + shipping

print(total)
```